# Multithreading program executing only last created thread?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, createthread

I have created 4 threads, but when i am executing this program I am getting this as output:

```
Thread #: 1  
Thread #: 2 
Thread #: 3 
Thread #: 3 
Thread #: 4 
Thread #: 4 
Thread #: 4
Thread #: 5 
Thread #: 5 
Thread #: 5
.
.
.
Thread #: 5 
Thread #: 5
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I have created only 4 thread so why is it showing thread #: 5
2. All the 4 threads created should run sequentially but why is it running only the last created thread?

Source code:

```
#include<windows.h>


HANDLE ThreadHandle[4];
DWORD dwThreadId[4];

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunction(LPVOID param)
{

    while (1)
    {

        printf("Thread #: %d\n", *((int*)param));
    }

    Sleep(10);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    static int i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        ThreadHandle[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, (LPVOID)&i, 0, &dwThreadId[i]);
        Sleep(10);

    }       
    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed in C. Writing to `ThreadHandle[4]` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: And the code won´t compile with the current {} usage. And concurrent console output is ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i` is a static variable - there's only one instance. You're passing its address to threads and dereferencing it every time you call `printf`. So when the main thread changes the value of `i`, *all* worker threads immediately see the new value. For that very reason you see thread #5 - that's the value of `i` once the `for()` loop ends.

Instead of `(LPVOID)&i`, pass `(LPVOID)i`, and inside the thread, use `(int)param` instead of `*((int*)param)`. Casting pointers to int and back is legal in C (albeit dangerous if misused).